# Hibernate search query filter performance impact versus ad-hoc query

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have a repetitive criteria (filter out entities the user does not have access to) that I use for several hibernate search queries.

Currently the criteria is generated by a function and is manually injected in all queries where it is required.

I was tempted to turn that into an hibernate search query filter.

I was wondering though what would be the performance impact. I.e. whether using a filter would be (much) slower than running an ad-hoc query?

There is going to be many users, many reads and not so many writes.

Answer (score 1):

The filter approach in Hibernate Search is very fast and based on Lucene filters. Restricting results per user seems to be a good fit for filters. Generally a filter should perform better than a query, especially if you use a caching filter. I would for sure try the filter approach. If you setup a little performance harness you can also easily measure the impact of the change.